# Can I request to be rehirable upon approval?

Tags: resignation

I am planning to resign in my company and join a new one, however the training in new company is so early and it is an opportunity I don't want to miss. Hence, I am planning to do an immediate resignation as I have this discussed with my manager previous months, but I did not formally send a letter/email or such. Now, as i need to join in new class as soon as possible, can I request my old company to make me rehirable within my immediate resignation letter? I value my old company and looking forward to go back in future.

Here is how I wish to end it then.
Sample:

> While I embark on this new chapter in my career, I would like to
> express my sincere hope that you will consider me as a candidate for
> rehire in the future. I have immensely enjoyed being part of the
> Company’s_Name family and would welcome the opportunity to contribute
> once again to the success of this exceptional organization.

Comment: Did you mean to say that you join a new company, but look forward to going back to the old company after certain time ?

Comment: "**can i request to my old company to make me rehirable within my immediate resignation letter?**" --- Wow. I have never seen that. It's possible, but it looks so strange to do that.

Comment: Your response is helpful too, i want to know what owners/company contributors feels as this is my first job and no idea so far, been with them for a long run like couple of years becoming a role model as i was able to provide huge impact in company’s numbers, here is i want to state it, still i know that this will be upon owner/companies decision

Comment: I shared above my sample thanks

Comment: This may not be the "most solid" question ever written in terms of expectations.  Still, I am certain many people have had just this quandary when leaving an established position that they liked for a more uncertain one, making it a valuable one.  Additionally, see that "hands off, new contributor" flag?  It's there for a reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that to re-hire you they would need to have a position open to hire you into. They almost certainly aren't going to hold a position open for you; the work needs to be done, and if you aren't there someone else has to be brought in to do it.

And if a position *is* open, you will be competing against everyone else who applies for that position.

If they've liked working with you, that plus your already knowing the company practices may give you an advantage in re-applying. On the other hand, the fact that you left once may make them concerned that you will quickly leave again, unless you have been there for enough years that they know you aren't just jumping around.

Realistically: You can always ask. Or at least tell them that you've enjoyed working there and, if this venture doesn't work out, would be interested in working with them again. That certainly beats leaving bad feelings behind you. Whether there is any chance it will actively improve your chances of being rehired is going to be a matter of luck more than anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful insight i will take this as positive feedback, appreciate your time and reply

Answer (score 4):

You can request, sure. Whether they'll comply or not, that is their prerogative and you do not have any control over that. Do what you think is best.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you give tons of notice, and go above and beyond what anybody would expect regarding training your replacement; the company could still decide that they don't want to rehire you.

There is also a chance the company will ignore anything in your resignation letter other then the notice date and the last day you will be working.

The fact that you request it, and that they act on your resignation letter, doesn't mean that have to accept your request.

But if you want to include it, go ahead, there is little harm in doing so.